# UML Class Method From Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

How does the direction of a message could determine the method of a class (of a sequence diagram actor) ?  I'd say the actor sending the message is the one having the method. Am I correct ?

[image]

And the classes For that are

[image]

Am I right or is it the other way around ?

Comment: I'm not sure what type of login system you have, but usually you put in the password with the login credentials. That's one step, not two.

Comment: @cricket_007 Point taken. Thats right. I did that just to draw more that one message.  Tell me one thig though, since EnterLogin() and EnterPassword() are implemented by COMPUTER , are  LOGIN and PASSWORD properties ok PERSON ?

Comment: A Person entity should not store its own password, only the identifier of the login, be that email or username, for example. Also, the `Enter` prefix is very verbose and completely unnecessary if you just implement the method with parameters like `login(id, password)`. A class diagram doesn't always match a sequence diagram.  The user sees a login screen and types a password. The computer is not spamming the user with an `AskPassword` function. You also are missing the error message response when the validation is not correct.

Comment: One thing that I think may help you is a tool that is more faithful to the UML specification. For example, MagicDraw offers to create an operation from a message, or the other way around. That would help you understand how things relate in UML. Consider downloading a copy and requesting an evaluation license.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Sending a message" is in most cases the same as "calling a method", which means that if an actor sends a message to the computer, then the computer needs to understand it / implement a method.

There is a difference (see here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852381/calling-a-method-or-sending-a-message-in-objective-c)) but essentially you "send a message" to an object, and the object decides what to do with it, in most cases it implements an appropriate method.

So to answer your question, the receiver of the message send should implement a method for it, not the sender.

Perhaps a pseudocode can also illustrate it:

```
class A {
    function hello() {
        b.someMessage();
        c.otherMessage();
    }
}

class B {
    function someMessage() {
        this.selfMessage();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot one thing. In my diagram, lets say there is a property called LOGIN.  With what you said LOGIN will be a property of PERSON and EnterLogin() a metho of COMPUTER right ??

Comment: No. Login is a method of a system class name Authentication. If it were the method of the user, why should it do a login at all?