# Cpp-Swift Interop fails with conformance to NSObject

Tags: c++, swift, interop

I have a project where I m making direct swift calls from cpp as introduced in swift5.9. Below is my swift class whose method is being invoked on cpp.

```
import Foundation

public class MySwiftClass
{
   public static func testInterop () -> Void
   {
     NSLog("----------- hey --------")
   }
}
```

I m able to successfully invoke 'testInterop()' in cpp with the above class, however if I add conformance to NSObject in the 'MySwiftClass' class, then the swift call in the below cpp code fails with the error

> No member named 'MySwiftClass' in namespace 'CoreModule'

where CoreModule is my swift target. Below is my Cpp code to invoke swift method:

```
#include "temp.hpp"
#include "CoreModule-Swift.h"

void
TempLogger::DisplayTempError ()
{
printf("\nthis is a temporary logger\n");

    CoreModule::MySwiftClass::testInterop ();
}
```

I m not able to identify why is adding the NSObject Conformance generating this error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts here:

1. if you want to use Objective-C (sub)classes in your C++ code, you'll need to use Objective-C++ files, so you'll need to change the file extension to `.mm`
2. Once you enter the Objective-C realm, there are no more namespaces, as Objective-C doesn't have support for them, so it's just `MySwiftClass` instead of `CoreModule::MySwiftClass`
3. Objective-C classes use a different method dispatch mechanism, which is named [message sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852381/calling-a-method-or-sending-a-message-in-objective-c), and which has a different syntax: `[MySwiftClass testInterop]`
4. In order to make the Swift functions available to Objective-C++, you'll need to either decorate them with `@objc`, or you can decorate the class with `@objcMembers`

Assembling all the above, this is how your `.mm` file could look:

```objectivec
#include "temp.hpp"
#include "CoreModule-Swift.h"

void
TempLogger::DisplayTempError ()
{
printf("\nthis is a temporary logger\n");

    [MySwiftClass testInterop];
}
```

Comment: Do we also require to annotate the swift function 'testInterop' with @objc?

Comment: Oh, yeah, missed mentioning about the `@objc` qualifier, updated the answer, thanks!